# how to do the Double tap and Pinch and Swipe control in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Please somebody Help me, How to do the Double tap and Pinch and Swipe control in windows phone 7

Answer (score 0):

Originally I've used GestureService from [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/). [Here](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-gestureservice-in-depth--key-concepts-and-api) is an article describing its usage.

However, that project has migrated to a new [page](http://phone.codeplex.com) which appears to be missing that service.

There is [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522499/is-there-a-high-level-replacement-for-the-wp7-toolkit-gestureservice) here on StackOverflow that is similar to your question, maybe it will help you.

Comment: Thank You So Much For Your Reply. Can you Tell me, How to Zooming The image When Double Tap Event Occur.

Comment: I cannot give a simple answer to this, it depends on the way you are showing your image.

Comment: I Want to Zoom the Image When Double Tap Event Occur on the Image and also want to See the next Image When Swipe the First Image.

Comment: This is rather complex answer and it requires me to practically implement your application for you. If you have RadControls, you can use their FilmStrip control for that purpose.